# disable add character when override keyListening in textArea - java

Tags: java, textarea, keylistener

I want override keyListening:

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    char c = e.getKeyChar();
    if(textComp.getSelectedText() != null){
         textComp.replaceSelection("p");
    }
}
```

I want selected Text is replace by "p" but it is replace by "p" + 'c'
How can I disable 'c' character

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, you can't, not with a `KeyListener`.  The character may already have been committed to the underlying `Document` of the text component before your `KeyListener` is notified.

Instead, you should be using a `DocumentFilter` instead, it's what it's designed to do, see [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter)

Comment: I can't extend 2 classes, and I extended class JFrame before.

Comment: I don't suggest extending anything.  Create a `DocumentFilter` of you own and apply it to the `Document` of the `JTextArea`....